# Странности в работе CommandBuilder

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server

при работе над дипломным проектом столкнулся с неправильной работой Commanduilder. Например, при отправке запроса на добавление записи в бд она добавляется дважды [image: Добавление записи] (возможно, это связано с добавлением записи как в DataSource, так и в DataGridView, однако к dgv данные привязываются в коде), так же при изменении записи разница между данными таблиц не фиксируются и запрос при этом выглядит крайне странно [image: Изменение записи1]
[image: Изменение записи2]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Вот листинг:

```
try
        {
            //происходит при изменении ячейки
            //dt.Rows[e.RowIndex][e.ColumnIndex] = suppliersGridView.CurrentCell.Value;
            //SQLHelper.UpdateData(q, ds);
        } catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex) { MessageBox.Show("Error", ex.Message); }
        if (e.ColumnIndex == suppliersGridView.ColumnCount - 1)
        {
            //происходит при изменении последней ячейки записи
            SQLHelper.ExecuteReader("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Suppliers', RESEED, " + e.RowIndex + ")");
            DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 1; i < suppliersGridView.ColumnCount; i++) {
                newRow[i] = suppliersGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value; }
            dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
            SQLHelper.UpdateData(q, ds);
        }
```

SQLHelper...

```
public static DataSet UpdateData(string query,DataSet ds)
        {
            SqlConnection con = GetConn();
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            MessageBox.Show(cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand().CommandText);
            MessageBox.Show(cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand().CommandText);
            MessageBox.Show(cmdBuilder.GetDeleteCommand().CommandText);
            adapter.Update(ds);
            ds.Clear();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            return ds;
        }
```

Comment: Пока я вижу одну проблему - полное игнорирование `IDisposable` https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects.

Comment: Где? Каждое подключение и каждая транзакция закрываются явно, строкой con.Close(), что эквивалентно Dispose(). Если в NewRow, то это объект BindingSource.Table.Row, который как все обычные динамические переменные выгружается после прохождения тела условного оператора. Больше я ничего здесь такого не вижу.

Comment: Ну значит вам виднее. Вы подключение закрываете, а адаптер с командой не диспозите. У вас откуда-то уверенность, что они сами задиспозятся при закрытии соединения, и вы так же уверены, что адаптер зафиналил датасет и т.д. В общем, лучше читать документацию и искать примеры, чем делать ни на чем основанные выводы. Это может быть не связано с проблемой дублирования, я не спорю. Но то что вы не навешиваете using на IDisposable думая что старший объект сделает это внезапно за вас - это не хорошо. Так же при возникновении исключения между Open и Close, соединение будет брошено открытым.

Comment: Код написан опираясь на эти https://metanit.com/sharp/adonetcore/3.3.php статьи, ничего про выгрузку адаптера, на сколько я помню, не было написано.

Comment: качество кода с метанита всегда было под большим вопросом, не аргумент. Опять же, это ваше приложение, я не настаиваю. Делайте как считаете нужным.

Comment: С вопросом оптимизации я думал заняться тогда когда программа будет полностью написана и осуществлять все что от нее требуется, сейчас меня волнует конкретно то, что написано в теме, оптимизация - дело второе, т.к. если ничего не работает, то и думать об этом не стоит. К вашим словам я все же прислушаюсь, однако с основной проблемой я так и не разобрался.

Comment: Самая большая оптимизация здесь - это начать использовать ORM, например Entity Framework, а для этого придется переписать почти всё. Смысл очень долго писать что-то для того чтобы потом это полностью переписать? Но вам виднее.

Comment: Чтоб вы понимали, я с дуру перекопировал этот код на каждую форму (их 5), хотя мог создать одну и просто менять название форм и наполнение dgv. Как говориться спешка, это не мое.

Comment: Дублирование кода это дублирование работы по его исправлению, да.

Comment: С orm не знаком, однако выбор sql был обоснован работой с данными из нескольких клиентов, что насколько я знаю предусмотрено sql сервером

Comment: Открытие бд наружу - это протиаозаконно. Я легко подключусь к открытой базе и всё удалю оттуда, пароли не помогут, я их лешко достанв из вашего же приложения. С базой должен работать сервер. А клиенты - сервером.

Comment: Дело в том, что пароли как раз находятся в бд, я хотел сначала наладить работу с локальной бд, а потом переместить ее на отдельный сервер

Comment: А что мне помешает залезть к вам в бд и забрать все что там лежит? К БД нельзя открывать доступ с внешней сети, никто так не делает. Это дырища в безопасности системы. Лучше разберитесь, почему.

Comment: Я займусь этим вопросом, когда у меня будет готово приложение

Comment: Начнете писать сервер и выкидывать весь код, связанный с работой с базой из приложения? Ну успехов вам. :)

Comment: Неужели соединение с локальной бд : public static SqlConnection GetConn()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;" +
                "AttachDbFilename=" + path + "\\Car_directory.mdf;Integrated Security=True;" +
                "Connect Timeout=30");
            return conn;
        }
Настолько отлично от серверной?

Comment: Конечно, плюс в серверах ADO.NET не используют, с ним очень неудобно работать, вместо этого используют ORM и подход к проектированию базы Code First, это когда вы создаете классы модели данных, а сервер сам создает таблицы в базе под эти данные. Уже давно никто на низком уровне не пишет SQL запросы для стандартных задач. Конечно, в SQL обязательно следует разбираться, но для повседневной разработки это не требуется. То есть все что вы написали с этими соединениями и DataTable - уже заведомо не нужно. Плюс для общего развития почитайте про шаблон проектирования MVP для Winforms, интересное.

Comment: С удовольствием бы почитал. если бы диплом не надо было сдавать 22  числа. К тому же, думаю что мне хватит sql, т.к. это приложение делается для диплома, а не для серьезной компании.